# spring-data-redis 1.7.2 Injection redisTemplate failed

Tags: java, spring, redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

When I use Spring Data Redis to inject `redisTemplate`, the following error occurs:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in com.worktime.configure.JpaConfigurationTest: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.<init>(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.<init>(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)V
at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.<init>(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:53)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet(RedisTemplate.java:117)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
... 40 more
```

Here is my code :

```
@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    nodes = new ArrayList<String>();
    nodes.add("10.10.13.174:7001");
    nodes.add("10.10.13.174:7002");
    nodes.add("10.10.13.174:7003");
    RedisClusterConfiguration conf = new RedisClusterConfiguration(nodes);
    conf.setMaxRedirects(1000);
    JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory(conf);

    return factory;
}

@Bean
RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<Object, Object>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    return redisTemplate;
}
```

My spring data redis version is 1.7.2, and redis version is 2.8.1.

Comment: Upgrade the Spring Core Framework to at least 4.2.1. Spring Data Redis uses a newer constructor, see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/serializer/support/DeserializingConverter.html#DeserializingConverter-java.lang.ClassLoader-)

Comment: I change to 4.3.2, it works well, thank you.^_^

Comment: @webdavid How to Configure the above as XML?, I'm having the same issue as described, Using Spring Data Redis 1.7.2.RELEASE and Spring 4.3.2. How to Configure RedisCacheManager for the same version?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below configuration to use with Spring Data Redis 1.7.2.RELEASE, This won't cause any injection issues.

```
    <cache:annotation-driven cache-manager="redisCacheManager" />

    <!-- Redis Connection Factory -->
    <beans:bean id="jedisConnectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
        p:host-name="${redis.host-name}" p:port="${redis.port}" p:use-pool="true" />

    <!-- Redis Template Definition -->
    <beans:bean id="redisTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
        p:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnectionFactory" p:keySerializer-ref="stringRedisSerializer"
        p:hashKeySerializer-ref="stringRedisSerializer" />

    <beans:bean id="stringRedisSerializer"
        class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer" />

    <!-- declare Redis Cache Manager -->
    <beans:bean id='redisCacheManager'
        class='org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager'
        c:redis-operations-ref='redisTemplate'>
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks you. But i had to change the Spring version.

Answer (score 1):

I only need to change the Spring version into the  project pom without change the bean definition.

```
<bean id="jedisConnectionFactoryStatic"     class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName"   value="#{confMasterRedisStatic.host}" />
    <property name="port"       value="#{confMasterRedisStatic.port}" />
    <property name="usePool"    value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="redisTemplateStatic" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.StringRedisTemplate"
        p:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnectionFactoryStatic" />
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!-- <spring.version>3.0.7.RELEASE</spring.version> -->
    <spring.version>4.3.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4.RELEASE</version>
    <!-- <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version> -->
</dependency>
```